# Peerjs is not retrieved in vue js

Tags: vue.js, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to use peerjs in vue app. So I added the cdn script in vue index.html file's header like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta data-n-head="true" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>peer</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.9/peer.min.js"></script>

  </head>
 <body>
 <div id="app"></div>
 <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Now in a components' mounted hook, I am doing this to just console the id

```
var peer1 = new Peer();
    peer1.on('open', function(id) {
    console.log('My peer1 ID is: ' + id);
});
```

Nothing happens.

I then created a simple html file and run that html file I was able to see the id.

Next I tired to see XHR tab, I see when running a plain html file, two ajax calls is sent and in the result an ID is returned. But in vue, there is nothing like this. All I get a socket that returns this values

```
{websocket: true, origins: ["*:*"], cookie_needed: false, entropy: 1058218289}
```

cookie_needed
:
false
entropy
:
1058218289
origins
:
["*:*"]
websocket
:
true

One more thing, peers js documentations says to use api key, but if I use api key nothing happens in vue or html. Without the key, in html file I get the id.

Anyone knows please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Did you encountered this error "VM335:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/username/eywraw8t/124472/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://0.peerjs.com:9000/peerjs/id?ts=15303302653340.8813677000256057'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Comment: Nope, nothing like this. no errors

Comment: Ohhk, It might be I tried the same in jsfiddle.net. Will try it locally.